# Linking OneDrive for Business storage with OneDrive consumer accounts?

Tags: onedrive, office365

I'm running into a frustrating problem with some of our employees.  We pay for Office 365 accounts and give them access to install all of the applications on their personal devices. With this they get 1TB of OneDrive for Business storage.

However many of these people use company phones as their only phone, something we are happy with, but want to be able to use backup their photos to their consumer OneDrive accounts which by default only have a very low 5GB storage.

Unless I'm mistaken there is no way to link the fact that they already pay for an Office 365 solution, therefore the ONLY solution is for them to pay an additional £60 - £80 a year for Office 365 again, this time Office 365 Personal which uses consumer OneDrive as the storage option?

This seems very user unfriendly. Especially given that you can only expand OneDrive consumer storage to a measly 50GB if you want to increase space alone with no additional features.

Is there a better solution here?

Comment: add your vote here: https://onedrive.uservoice.com/forums/262982-onedrive/suggestions/6621582-allow-automatic-upload-of-photos-and-video-from-mo

Comment: Thanks, that is useful for some users but I guess what I'm looking for is slightly different. I think if you are paying Office 365 Business I'd like a way for that 1TB of storage to be shared between a Personal and Business account that could be linked in some way. After doing some reading it appears that the back ends are hugely different so maybe this is difficult.

Comment: Yes, OneDrive for Business is SharePoint behind the scenes, OneDrive personal is a different platform. Seeing that both platforms use different accounts to authenticate, I don't really see that the integration you describe would be happening easily or anytime soon.